# Spot NDVI spatial reference system

Tags: coordinate-system, australia, ndvi

I have a series of spot NDVI data for Australia and I need to extract some information from it. Unfortunately there is no spatial reference system attached to it. [This](https://www.dropbox.com/l/DurObHGOPr1WlJG5ph61q8) is one example of the data (HDF files). Do I have the wrong dataset? Is there any other NDVI products useful for Australia?

Comment: The 0001_LOG.TXT file states that it's unprojected, WGS84 (it also says plate carree, but that's what you get when you display lat-lon data in 2D). When you display the data, are you seeing an extent that isn't in decimal degrees?

Comment: yes, it is not in decimal degree. It is writen unknown units.